# Dependency Injection (using simple injector) on a WCF Service hosted in a Managed Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, windows-services, simple-injector

I'm creating a WCF service hosted on a Windows Service as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx.

My service has some dependencies.

Which would be the right way to apply DI here using Simple Inyector.

I read about the SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory class here https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wcfintegration.html, but it appears that it only works for IIS hosted services.

On the 1st sample I assume that I register the types on the Main() method, but how should I create the ServiceBase?

And more important, how should I call (or create) the servicehost instance. Should I get the container from somewhere and directly create the instance of the real service using it. That seems pretty ugly for me

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type using the  
    // container directly
    serviceHost =  serviceHost = new ServiceHost(container.GetInstance<ICalculatorService>());

    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net). Section 7.3 goes into some detail about how to configure WCF for DI (which is not something I have done, so I am just leaving a comment). I find it useful to build my own DI integration components because often (as in your case) the stock ones from 3rd parties do not fit your application's use case, and the book tells you exactly how to build such an integration with WCF.

Comment: I agree with NightOwl. I never have any problems with WCF because I use WCF service classes as humble objects and see it as part of my composition root. This means that my WCF services contain no application logic and just resolve a service from the container that does contain logic.

Comment: [this post](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95) may be of use to you ...

Answer (score 0):

This blog post provides a possible approach: [Decouple WCF Services from their DI Container with Common Instance Factory](https://www.dotnetcodegeeks.com/2012/10/decouple-wcf-services-from-their-di.html)

The relevant code for creating the servicehost instance:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost;
var serviceBaseAddress = new Uri('http://localhost:8000/GreetingService');
switch (containerType)
{
    case ContainerType.Ninject:
        serviceHost = new NinjectServiceHost<GreetingService>
            (CreateNinjectContainer(), typeof(GreetingService), serviceBaseAddress);
        break;
    case ContainerType.SimpleInjector:
        serviceHost = new SimpleInjectorServiceHost<GreetingService>
            (CreateSimpleInjectorContainer(), typeof(GreetingService), serviceBaseAddress);
        break;
}
```